# How to repeat specific test method of a class N times in Pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

Lets say I've a class

```
class TestSome:
    def test_a(self):
        pass

    def test_b(self):
        pass
```

Where `test_a` is always executed once and `test_b` could be executed N times

Is there any approach in pytest to do so?

Comment: `def test_b_10(self): for _ in range(10): test(b)`?

Comment: Do you mean calling N times with different parameters? If yes, look at https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html otherwise, could you elaborate on why you want to call the test N times?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-repeat/

Answer (score 0):

You can try parameterize

```
import pytest


class TestSome:
    def test_a(self):
        pass

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("count", range(3))
    def test_b(self,count):
        pass
```

This will execute `test_b` 3 times